# Batman Arkham Series thinks I have surround sound

Tags: batman-arkham-city, batman-arkham-asylum

I got the game this week in the epic store and at first there where no issues. But since I started it up the second time it seems to think I have surround sound. When I turn the camera away from an audio source, the sound gets so quiet I can barely hear it. I already checked my speakers, set them to surround and then back to stereo, but that didn't help. The game itself seems to have no options for that. The issue also remains when I use headphones.

**Update:**
I finished the game and proceeded to Arkham City, which also has the same issues. This time it was from the start. Maybe I'm imagining things but I could swear when I first started Arkham Asylum the sound was fine. I noticed it immediately after loading it up the second time.